# add child document without existing parent doc in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

When I index a child document without an existing parent document (I am passing random parent id) it works without error and indexes child document. I expect it to give an error so I could check whether parent doc exist or not. How will I prevent it to be indexed without proper parent document?

Comment: are you using PUT or POST?

Comment: I am using [pyes](http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/pyes.es.html) module. As I see from `wireshark` it uses POST

Comment: So in REST APIs POST is generally create, and elasticsearch is probably being nice enough to create the related parent and give it an id for you. Try using CURL from the command line (or ES browser plugin Sense) to PUT that same request, I bet it errors out.

Comment: ```curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/reply?parent=4235436' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
'```

I indexed with this command and it worked properly, parent id does not exist.

Comment: I think you should revise your implementation. Parent-child is as named a relation between two object. Using random id is like ignoring this relation which is a I think not a good choice. Could you explain more what you want to do and maybe we can provide help with another implementation.

Comment: I create two mappings on an index named `twitter`. These are `tweet` and `reply`. While creating `reply` mapping I used following command ```curl -XPOST localhost:9200/twitter/reply/_mapping -d '{
  "reply":{
    "_parent": {"type": "tweet"}
  }
}'``` . If I try to insert a document in reply without passing a parent_id it gives error as expected. I can reach both parent and child documents that I indexed for trial purpose. My only problem (I don't know whether it is a problem or not), I am able to index a child document with an parent id which actually does not exist among parent documents.

Comment: .. and when I index non-existing parent document after indexing child,  it is successfully queried later with `has_child` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how ElasticSearch actually works (as far as undestand it). It doesn't have reference constaints. ElasticSearch is not an RDBMS that makes a huge focus on a referential integrity. ES makes focus on the performace, availability, etc - the kind of things for which you have to sacrifice integraty to some extent, as ensuring integraty is in most cases a costly thing. ES is often seen (and sometimes actually used) as an object-oriented NoSQL data source. And for NoSQL DBs lacking of referencial integraty is a common thing.

You can read more about this for example here - https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-as-nosql/

> Most relational databases also let you specify constraints to define what is and isn’t consistent. For example, referential integrity and uniqueness can be enforced. You can require that the sum of account movements must be positive and so on. Document oriented databases tend not to do this, and Elasticsearch is no different.